# Asp.Net MVC - Check for a route value in the Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

The question is about the homepage of my site.
The site is localized in 2 languages, the default language is IT, the alternative one is EN.

My home page is:

```
www.mysite.com
```

When English is selected, the address is:

```
www.mysite.com/en
```

The `{language}` param is in my `RouteData`.

Of course, if I type `www.mysite.com/it` it works and it's the same of `www.mysite.com`

What I would do is, in my Action method, checking if the `'it'` string is present in the url, and if it's there, make a PermanentRedirect to the `www.mysite.com` address.

I could do this by searching through the `Request.RawUrl` string, but I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using model binding - just add the parameter to your action. Note that in this case, `language` parameter may get its value extracted from query string or form values too, only if it will not be present in url.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
        {
           ///
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Or the alternative way, manually extract route value. In your action

```
        string language = RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
        {
           ///
        }
```

Comment: I know about ModelBinding or RouteData collection, this is not my case. My RouteData always contains the Language parameter, the EN value is the default value, so if the address is just www.mysite.com the EN value is in RouteData. What I need is checking if the EN value is in the Url string, maybe I can do this only checking into the string.